# Route homepage to Index inside Areas?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, area

I want to use Areas for my RazorPage 3.1 Core project. However, I can't seem to redirect the homepage from
`http://localhost:<port>` to `http://localhost:<port>/Default/Index` and the moment I use Areas and move my Pages folder into the Areas/Default/Pages I get an obvious 404 at my homepage. Every time I launch the project I get a 404 now for the homepage.

Or am I supposed to have 1 Pages folder outside of the Areas folder with the index as seen in the image below? That would be weird.

[image]

I tried everything I could find but I can't figure it out. I think it must be set somewhere in the Startup.cs:

```
            services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Default/Index", ""); // Or something?
        });
```

and:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Default/Index");
}
```

This didn't work for me:

- https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/areas#configuration
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1#areas-with-razor-pages

Comment: Or am I supposed to have the homepage outside of the Areas folder at all times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Route homepage to Index inside Areas

It seems that you'd like to display `index` page under `Default` area folder while user access at the root URL of your website.

To achieve the requirement, you can try to do URL rewrite operation like below.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path=="/")
        {
            context.Request.Path = "/Default/Index";
        }

        await next.Invoke();
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Test Result

[image]